# Google Maps API Android

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps-android-api-2, google-play-services, sample

I have this sample application loaded into Eclipse:

> C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\samples\maps

I noticed I had to add the jar file `android-support-v4.jar` from:

> C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk\extras\android\support\v4

in order for things to build properly.

---

So far I have tried running the application on my Galaxy S3 which is an actual device not a virtual one. I can't get the Basic Map demo to pull up a map at all on that device yet. I'm not sure why that is so I am trying to get to the bottom of that.

Also I tried running also on a virtual device: 
Galaxy Nexus (4.65", 720x1280 xhdpi)
Target: Android 4.1.2 API Level 16

On that virtual device I get an activity that comes up prompting me to install Google Play Services but, when I click the OK button the virtual device stops responding for some reason.

Does anyone have any tips on how I can get the Google Maps Demos running on one of my devices either be it the Galaxy S3 or a virtual device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure API KEY is proper and add google_play_services_lib as library project.I tried panorama example and its working fine in samsung s2.

Comment: Yes. I see now there must be a proper key in place. Once that is in the maps came right up. Thank you for your reply.